# Cordova Firebase Push Notifications IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap

first post here, please be nice :D

Currently building a cordova/phonegap application with the plugin: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

Notifications arrive perfectly fine on android and in the xcode console for IOS. However not on the IOS device itself.

See logs in Xcode. Last part after sending a notification via Firebase.
[See Logs XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Gpt.png)

I have tried reinstalling everything (Pods, Plugin..), Removing the IOS Platform/adding it again, playing around with the Plist file: Location/content...

Referring to the logs, it seems like something in the .js file (import/initialise...) Have not figured that out yet...

LOGS in Xcode:

"The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize_firebase_in_your_app."

"The object  does not respond to -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:, nor -messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:. Please implement -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken: to be provided with an FCM token."

"Error in Success callbackId: FirebasePlugin1611338129 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: show_push_notification"

See index.js: This function is called onDeviceReady: function(){....}
(Android working fine!)

```
   setupFirebase: function() {

     window.FirebasePlugin.grantPermission(function(){
            console.log("Permission is granted for iOS");
        }, function(error){
            alert(error);
        });

      window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function(token) {
      // Tell backend token
      }, function(error) {
          console.error(error);
      });

      // Get notified when a token is refreshed
      window.FirebasePlugin.onTokenRefresh(function(token) {
          // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
          console.log("Refresh to get new token: " + token);
      }, function(error) {
          alert(error);
      });

      window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(notification) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(notification));
          show_push_notification(notification);
      }, function(error) {
          console.error(error);
      });
```

},

Comment: Try sending push notifications from https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher and see whether you are getting them or not.